# How to create user that I can connect with?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL newbie here,

I've installed MySQL on my Windows 10 machine and can connect using MySQL Workbench with the root username and everything works as promised.

However, now I want to create another user to connect with and give that user access to just one database on the server.

I've created the user with these commands:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'f^rest_of_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I've created the database with this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpress
```

SO, now I tried to create a connection in MySQL Workbench using that user and the password and it fails.
The error message says:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'user' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306

Please:
1 Check that MySQL is running on address localhost
2 Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the user user has rights to connect to loclahost from your address (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for loclahost connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

What is my next move?

Thanks,
Owen

Comment: if you are using mysql workbench why not create there the user.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I post a question....

Turns out I needed to specify the "Installation Type" of custom,
the "Configuration File Section" of mysqld
and the "Windows Service Name" of MySQL80

(Ended up copying the working root connection and changing the username and password).